# How can I fix this jagged Shadows?

Tags: modeling, shadows, eevee-render-engine

I already subdividied the surface, but still getting this raw shadows in between of the spheres.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you used boolean modifier? What is your lightning sun or lamp?

Comment: I used a lamp. I didn´t used a boolean modifier ¿should I?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. I suppose you use Blender 2.80 Beta and Eevee?

Comment: Well probably not, I thought you maybe used it so it resulted in this topology. Try maybe using sun or secondary light source it may be just lack of light in scene, could you upload .blend file so we can look further in it?

Answer (score 9):

You can increase the size of the Cube texture for the light and check Soft Shadows.

Shadows in EEVEE are created by rendering a depth texture from the light source that are then matched up with the cameras depth texture. It's then possible to see where the depth from the light fails to reach the current pixel. The downside with this technique is it requires fairly high resolution and can still cause a set of unwanted behaviours and artefacts. But that is the price we pay to get crazy fast rendering compared to raytracing.

By using soft shadows EEVEE does a set of these light depth passes at a slight offset that are then used to soften the shadow out a bit. You can adjust the Radius on the light to adjust the smoothing.

[image]

Comment: If that's still not enough, you might try to change the Method from ESM to VSM. It uses more memory though.

Comment: Regarding ESM vs VSM, that setting was removed in 2.82: https://blenderartists.org/t/is-esm-vsm-gone/1217464